# Why Collectors.groupingBy gets confused with identity function?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I'm trying to count occurrences of integers in an array using `Collectors.groupingBy` from Java 8 API but I'm getting some strange compilation errors.

Here is my code:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3);
Map<Integer, Integer> x = l.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));
```

Sadly, this won't compile, resulting in the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
        Map<Integer, Integer> x = l.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));
                                                    ^
    inferred: Integer
    equality constraints(s): Integer,Long
1 error
```

It seems to be a generic type issue, because when I remove the generic Map type, it compiles. Here is another test:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3);
Map x = l.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));

System.out.println(x);
```

And the output is right as expected:

```
{1=3, 2=1, 3=4}
```

Any ideas of how to solve that without the need of casting all the types here and there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do:

```
Map<Integer, Long> x = l.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));
```

then your code will compile just fine.

The reason is that the `Collectors.counting()` method is defined as:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Long> counting()
```

Here, the third type-parameter denotes the type which will be used in the `BinaryOperator` that is used for calculating the count.

Note that when you remove the type-parameter for the `Map`:

```
Map x = l.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));
```

then the statement successfully compiles, because you're actually working with the raw version of `Map`, i.e. the type for both keys and values will be `Object` (which is compatible with `Long`, `Integer` and friends). However, using raw types is something that should be avoided, as you can get annoying `ClassCastException`(s) at Runtime.

Comment: Awesome, believe me or not I've end up finding the solution while fighting with my IDE and was coming back to SO to answer my own question and then I noticed that you already answered! This community is awesome, thanks @kocko and JonSkeet

Answer (score 5):

`counting()` is declared as:

```
static <T> Collector<T,?,Long>
```

... whereas you're trying to use it as if it produces an `Integer`.

If you change your code to:

```
Map<Integer, Long> x = l.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));
```

... it will compile with no problems. Note that in your current code using the raw type, your output *actually* has `Long` values rather than `Integer` values... it's just you can't tell that from the string representation.